# Map creation API for fictional interactive maps?

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I want to make an interactive map web application for a game that I play. Basically I want it to be a kind of Google maps clone, where I have a vector-based graphic of the region area and I can zoom in and out to reveal certain level of detail.

My research into map APIs has returned little results. OpenStreetMaps and Google Maps only allow custom maps with real geolocation data. My project requires the creation of a map with nonexistent locations. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you not use "real" GPS coordinates but just use the fictional background map?

Comment: so pick an arbitrary location on a real map with real coordinates and then force render the fake map tiles on top of it?

Comment: I think that's the best solution yes. GIS tools like google maps or OpenStreetMaps should allow you to pick a different image as the base layer. I know OSM allows this. The GPS Lat Long coordinates (between -90 and +90 each) offer as good a scale as any to then locate your fictional positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use "real" GPS coordinates and then customise the base layer beneath. The GPS Lat Long coordinates (between -90 and +90 each) offer as good a scale as any to then locate your fictional positions.

Google Maps has an API that allows putting custom layers and base maps here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes

OpenStreetMaps will also allow this. Some recommended guides available here:

https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/

Good luck!